# Get an image for all the items in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I want to get an image (file) from every item (rendered like when in inventory or in NEI). I've done many research about how to do this but without result. Every time they're saying to get the IBakedModel of every item but there are blocks that are using TESR (TileEntitySpecialRenderer) for example the Chest and they have no TextureAtlasSprite. 
I've also tried to understand how the items are rendered. They are using GL11 to render them but I've no idea how to get the image just for a precise item.
I've tried to extract the images from the jar files but there are some that are not there and for the items with multiple layers there are into multiple files.

Does anyone have an idea how too achieve what I'm trying to do ?
Thanks a lot :D

Comment: 1) What version of Minecraft? 2) Some of those "images" outright don't exist. Blocks are not rendered as flat images in the UI, they're rendered in 3D as 3D objects using an orthographic camera.

Comment: @Draco18s it's the 1.12.2 and yes I know that they are rendered as 3D object but I'm looking for a way to get the image like when rendered in the inventory for example.

Comment: Honestly, I'd scrape the Minecraft wiki instead of trying to get the game to do it.

Comment: I've already done that :D But I will try to find a workaround. Thanks anyway